# Add directory to manpath based on users input

Tags: shell-script, directory-structure

Using: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Editor: Nano

I am working on a small shell script for college and it needs to have menu with a range of options available to the user. One of the options is to "add a directory to the manual path based on user input". I thought I had the correct answer based on materials given to me but it isn't working?

the current location of manpath is "/usr/bin/manpath"

This is my code so far:

```
two() {
read -p"Please enter a directory to be added to the MANPATH: " dir
manpath=/usr/share/man$dir:$manpath; export manpath
#TO SHOW IT HAS WORKED 
which manpath
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the manpath is where `man` finds pages, not where the command itself is supposed to be. does that help at all?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment :) unfortunately not, i've tried replacing manpath with man and nothing works. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

`manpath` is a *command* that (executed without any flags) simply displays the paths where `man` looks for its pages. In other words, you cannot add a path to the command `manpath`.

Below is an illustration on how you can add a path - in this case the directory `/foobar` - to the already existing paths (on Debian 10).

```
# Original paths
manpath
/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man

# Adding a path
export MANPATH=$(manpath):/foobar

# Result
manpath
manpath: warning: $MANPATH set, ignoring /etc/manpath.config
/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/foobar
```

Does this make things a bit clearer?

Please run: `man manpath`. Where you will find:

```
DESCRIPTION
       If $MANPATH is set, manpath will simply display its contents and issue a warning.
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. It has made things a lot clearer to me and has allowed me to complete the my task. Thank you again :-)

Comment: I am glad to hear that @Steven, Happy Hacking! :)